# Problems with music playback - Music File corrupt?

Tags: music-player, htc-desire-hd, headphones

I have an HTC Inspire 4G (Desire HD, Ace), and whenever I have headphones plugged in and am listening to music, the music player will randomly start playing new songs, pausing and starting a new one every second or so, until I unplug my headset. I plug my headset back in, then at some point my phone will do this again, and I have to start this process all over again.

It started on the stock sense rom using the stock sense player when I first got the phone. I then tried using winamp, same problem. I rooted the phone, flashed CM7, and am now using Cloudskipper as my music player, still the problem persists. I even unchecked headset controls, still continued. I even tried another pair of headphones, however both were BEATS headphones. What is going on??

Comment: +1 for great question. Thanks for including your troubleshooting steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was something wrong with the firmware in the phone. I installed a new kernel with the beats audio mod and everything worked correctly after that.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the phone has a problem with that type of headphones. I'd try a different few different types of headphones.

It could also be a hardware problem with the headphone port.

Comment: I tried a different pair of headphones and still the same problem. If it's a hardware problem with the port is there any way I can fix it?

Comment: got insurance on it?

Answer (score 0):

Check you audio socket for possible debris.